# Change a single value of an SVG path using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm working with an inline SVG.

Example:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 8 8">
  <path d="m0 0 h8 v4 l-4 4 l-4-4 z"/>
</svg>
```

I would like to change the `l-4 4` command to `l-4 0` inside the `d` attribute using JavaScript. I don't want to edit the entire path, just the `l` command. Maybe somehow getting the `l` command with coordinates `-4 4` and setting them to `-4 0`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Although you can replace only part of the string It's easier to replace the whole d attribute. Mind you that in certains paths you can find the search string (the l-4 4 string) several times.

Comment: Yes, I know that. Maybe specifying which occurrence has to be modified is a better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript doesn't have a very rich api for interacting with svg. There are probably libraries that fill in this gap, but I haven't looked. If this is all you want to do, you could try something like this:

```js
const svg = document.querySelector("svg");
svg.innerHTML = svg.innerHTML.replace("l-4 4", "l-4 0");
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 8 8">
  <path d="m0 0 h8 v4 l-4 4 l-4-4 z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Seems pretty rich to me: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#DOMInterfaces and https://github.com/progers/pathseg

Comment: I guess rich is relative.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! This is what I was trying to do. But like @enxaneta said: “in certains paths you can find the search string (the l-4 4 string) several times”, specifying which occurrence has to be modified is a better approach in some cases.

Comment: or notation can be ``m0,0h8v4l-4,4l-4-4z``

Comment: Yes, but what's the difference?